# Let $S = \{\ x \in R : x^{6} - x^{5} ≤ 100\}\ $ and $T = \{\ x^{2}-2x : x \in (0, \infty)\}\ $..

Tags: calculus

Let $S = \{\ x \in R : x^{6} - x^{5} ≤ 100\}\ $ and $T = \{\ x^{2}-2x : x \in (0, \infty)\}\ $ Then the set $S$ intersection $T$ is closed and bounded. (True/false)

The range of set $T$ is $[-1, \infty]$ which is closed.

I need to find set $S$ but I don't know how to do it. I can use the sign scheme of polynomial $x^{6} -x^{5} - 100$ to see where the value of polynomial is negative. But finding out its roots is not an easy task

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

$S$ is certainly closed as $\le$ is a "closed condition" (formally, pre-image o fthe closed set $(-\infty,100]$ under the continuous map $x\mapsto x^ 6-x^5$). Henec $S\cap T$ is closed.

We already know that $S\cap T$ is bounded from below and only need to check for an upper bound. Note that the function $x\mapsto x^6-x^5$ goes to $+\infty$ as $x\to\pm\infty$ because the $x^6$ is dominating. Hence for $|x|$ large enough, $x^6-x^5$ exceeds any given limit, such as $100$. We conclude that $S$ is bounded.